How can I write bare metal C programs that run on the Raspberry Pi?
I'm looking for a way to compile C programs into binaries which run on my Raspberry Pi 5, without any operating system, and so that the program gets full access to all hardware. What cross-compiler can I use for this purpose? What are the limitations of this cross-compiler? Can it compile any C program? Can it compile multithreaded programs? Is the GNU ARM toolchain any good? How does the cross compiler generally work?
I thought it would be simple to find a cross-compiler because it feels like a (relatively) straightforward program. But when learning about them, I encountered such seemingly extraneous things as required extra assembly programs, linkers, extra scripts, etc. I don't understand why any of this is necessary when all I need is my C program to be translated into ARM machine code. How do I learn this system?

What have you tried already? Which tutorial are you following? Please add all links to the question.

At least a few dozen lines of assembly are required, and you will be able to write the rest in C.

Your question is too broad. You ask "how to write a c program", then you ask about a cross compiler, asking about if a compiler can compile. Consider tutoring, a teacher, and a lot of hours to learn it. There is a lot of documentation about a lot of stuff on the internet, consider resaerching.

How do you plan to load and run your program?

the bare metal forum at the pi site is very good and has many bare metal examples.   the tools are trivial to come by...


What cross-compiler can I use for this purpose?

arm-none-eabi-gcc

What are the limitations of this cross-compiler?

(?) There are millions of limitations any compiler has.

Can it compile any C program?

It wouldn't be a compiler otherwise.

Can it compile multithreaded programs?

A compiler does not run programs. A compiler may compile a program that is multithreaded. A compiler might itself be multithreaded. Gcc itself is not multithreaded.
The intention stated is to run a "bare matel" program. "Multithreading" is something you have to implement yourself from scratch if you intent to implement it.

Is the GNU ARM toolchain any good?

GNU ARM toolchain is "any good".

How does the cross compiler generally work?

The same way as a normal compiler, just generates code using a different instruction set.

why any of this is necessary

The goal stated in the question is to write a program without an operating system. A lot is necesserary when writing a program without an operating system, in particular a lot of linking and assembly, exactly because there is no operating system to manage a lot for you. In particular your program "gets full access to all hardware" so you have to know how to and where to access "all hardware" and communicate that intention using a programming langauge.

How do I learn this system?

As any learning goes. Learn one thing, then another, then another. You might be interested in some good C book, C courses and tutoring.
